# Mongoose: Whats wrong w/ my findByIdAndUpdate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

my idea is very simple, it is get the update value from req.body, but it doenst work properly, the data never change in the mongodb.

already tried the {$set: email, password}

```
    const id = { _id: req.params.id };
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    let user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { email, password });

    if (!user) {
        return res.json({ message: "error"});
    }

    return res.json({
        user: user,
        updated: true
    })
```

Comment: Note that your code as it stands now (also after applying the answer) will not work as you have probably intended since `user`  will still be the **not** updated version. You have to pass `{new: true}` as a third parameter to have the updated user being returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you passing a object into to `id` field when all it needs is a string/ObjectId

```
const { email, password } = req.body;

let user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { email, password });

if (!user) {
    return res.json({ message: "error"});
}

return res.json({
    user: user,
    updated: true
})
```

Comment: @JoãoVitor you are welcome, don't forget to mark the response as answered. You click the tick next to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Expression :

```js
    const id = { _id: req.params.id };
```

creates an Object named id with a field _id set to the actual id value from the params.
So eventually what you end up doing is passing an entire object instead of an id in the first argument to findByIdAndUpdate which only accepts an id as the first parameter.
If you still want to use the object just replace id with id._id in the method findByIdAndUpdate. Which you would then write as :

```js
    let user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id._id, { email, password });
```